# How to disable button action on Action sheet added via UIAlertViewController - (iOS 9/10)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

I have made an ActionSheet like this:

[image]

Now I want change the color `Cancel` And `Delete` to give the feel like they are `disabled`.

I am able to change the color of all buttons but not individuals.

I have tried using categories but I am keep getting `warining` that `ActionSheet` is `Depreciated`. And the code didn't work also.

I have written this Code:

```
      - (void)setButton:(NSInteger)buttonIndex toState:(BOOL)enabled {
for (UIView* view in self.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnabled:)])
            {
                UIButton* button = (UIButton*)view;
                button.enabled = enabled;
            }
        }
        buttonIndex--;
    }
}
 }
```

Is it possible to give disabled look to some of the buttons of `Action sheet` presented via `AlertViewController`.

Below is the my code to present Action Sheet:

```
 UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Action Sheet" message:@"Using the alert controller" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
 [actionSheet.view setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // Cancel button tappped.


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // Distructive button tapped.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Group 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // Distructive button tapped.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // OK button tapped.

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}]];


// Present action sheet.
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: If you want to *disable* the actions why don't you omit them conditionally?

Comment: @vadian I have to show to User that these are available options. But You can't select Until you fulfil the condition. (like IAP)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is use the `setEnabled` property of `UIAlertAction`.

This will render your button as 'greyed out'.

I have modified a piece of your code to incorporate this change:

```
UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // OK button tapped.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}];

[action setEnabled:NO];
[actionSheet addAction:action];
```

Ofcourse, you **can't click on the button** after you disable it.

Other options would involve using `UIAlertActionStyle`.
There are three:

```
UIAlertActionStyleDefault,
UIAlertActionStyleCancel,
UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
```

`UIAlertActionStyleDefault` will render your button with `tintColor`.

`UIAlertActionStyleCancel` will render your button on the bottom of the sheet.

`UIAlertActionStyleDestructive` renders your button with a 'red' color. (Think: Delete button)

Comment: Is this works in swift? As I tried actionSheetController.isEnabled = false. But gives error "Value of type 'UIAlertController' has no member 'isEnabled'.

Comment: Yeah, this should also work in Swift. Please note I'm setting `setEnabled` on  `UIAlertAction`, not on `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Yup! I noticed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Get the actions array and change the state for the action you want.
This way you can change the state even after adding the action.

Here is the sample code.

```
NSArray* actionlist = actionSheet.actions;
UIAlertAction * action2 = [actionlist objectAtIndex:1];    
action2.enabled = false;

// Present action sheet.
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```